# Stitching in OpenCv C++

Tags: c++, opencv

Can anyone here please tell me How Stitching works in OpenCv. I mean How much pictures should be same for stitching? I have three pictures of a chair from different sides with black background and with perspective that the first one is 80% same with the second one and third one in 80% same with second one. I want to stitch them and then do something like a 3d modelling with rotations on it. My Code for stitching is given below here

int main()

```
{



    //stiching function
    Mat img1 = imread("back.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Mat img2 = imread("back1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    Mat img3 = imread("back2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    vector<Mat> image;
    Mat stitchedImage;
    Stitcher stitchx = Stitcher::createDefault(true);
    image.push_back(img1);
    image.push_back(img2);
    image.push_back(img3);
    Stitcher::Status stitcherStatus = stitchx.stitch(image, stitchedImage);
    imshow("Stitched", stitchedImage);




    Mat ou;


    rotateImage(stitchedImage, ou, /*-30*/-90,/* 20*/-170.90, 90, 10, 0, -260, 250);
    imshow("o", ou);

    return 0;
}
```

When Debugging the line stitchx.stitch it says ERR_NEED_MORE_PICS and on imshow it gives an exception like this below.
Unhandled exception at 0x77002F71 in StitchedPerspec.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00DBF210.

please can any one help me through this ! 
I can't upload images here I don't know why.. But please if anyone willing to help me send me your email id so I can show you the pictures I have. 
I will be very Thankful..

Answer (score 0):

Without pictures uploaded we cannot help you. But probably there are not enought features detected in your images that 'stitch' can use...